# adding values to diagonals of matrix using element-wise addition in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am writing a script that operates on matrices, and I have run into the problem of needing to add the sum of the diagonals of a previous matrix to the diagonal elements of a new matrix. The code I have so far for this particular function (described in more detail below) is:

```
t = 1;
for k = (m-1):-1:-(m-1)
    C = bsxfun(@plus, diag(B, k), d);
    g(t) = sum(diag(B, k));
    t = t + 1;
end
```

where d is a 1x3 array, and C is supposed to be a 3x3 array; however, C is being output as a 1x3 array in such a way that the first diagonal is being summed and added to d, then the main diagonal is being summed and added to d, and the final diagonal is being summed and added to d.

Is there a way I can get the values of C to be such that the first diagonal is the sum of it's individual elements added to the last element of d, the main diagonal's individual elements added to the middle element of d, and the bottom diagonal's elements added to the first element of d? (while still working for any array size?)

Here is a picture that describes what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Adding sums to diagonals]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include numerical examples showing what you want? I can't figure out what you want to do from your question

Comment: Sure thing! Just added an imgur link with a picture of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If `B` is `3x3`, shouldn't `d` be `1x5`?

Comment: Interesting question! And well described

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`toeplitz`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) to generate a matrix containing the values that need to be added to your original matrix:

```
M = [5 5 5; 7 7 7; 9 9 9]; %// data matrix
v = [1 11 4 3 2]; %// data vector
S = toeplitz(v);
S = S(1:(numel(v)+1)/2, (numel(v)+1)/2:end);
result = M+S;
```

Or, as noted by @thewaywewalk, you can do this more directly as follows:

```
M = [5 5 5; 7 7 7; 9 9 9]; %// data matrix
v = [1 11 4 3 2]; %// data vector
result = M + toeplitz(v(size(M,1):-1:1), v(size(M,2):end));
```

Comment: As my other solutions turned out to be wrong, and toeplitz is the only one really reliable for all shapes of `M`, I rolled your answer back.

Comment: Elegant solution with `toeplitz`!

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! Very handy function for these diagonal things

Comment: I actually have another question - can this be modified to do element-wise addition to the columns of a matrix? Very similar to the question I posed initially, except to the columns instead of the diagonals?

Comment: Nevermind! I found that the easiest way to do this (comment above) was just to repmat the single column/row matrices containing the values I wanted to sum with, and then just do simple matrix addition.

Comment: @bieberman No need to use expensive `repmat` there, just do `bsxfun(@plus,B,d)`!

Comment: @bieberman `bsxfun` is perfect for that: faster than `repmat` and more elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `B` to be a square shaped matrix, listed in this post would be one [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based vectorized approach. Here's the implementation -

```
N = size(B,1) %// Store size of B for later usage

%// Find a 2D grid of all indices with kth column representing kth diagonal of B
idx = bsxfun(@plus,[N-numel(B)+1:N+1:N]',[0:2*N-2]*N)  %//'

%// Mask of all valid indices as we would see many from the 2D grid 
%// going out of bounds of 2D array, B
mask = idx>numel(B) | idx<1

%// Set all out-of-bounds indices to one, so that in next step 
%// we could index into B in a vectorized manner and sum those up with d
idx(mask)=1
sum1 = bsxfun(@plus,B(idx),d(:).') %//'

%// Store the summations at proper places in B with masking again
B(idx(~mask)) = sum1(~mask)
```

Sample run -

```
B =
     1     9     0
     7     9     4
     6     8     7
d =
     4     9     5     8     2
B =
     6    17     2
    16    14    12
    10    17    12
```

Answer (score 2):

### Code:

The following code adds the sums of the diagonals of `A` to the corresponding diagonals in the matrix `B`. The code works for matrices `A`, `B` of equal size, not necessarily square.

```
A = magic(4);
B = magic(4); 

D = bsxfun(@minus, size(A,2)+(1:size(A,1)).', 1:size(A,2)); %'
sumsDiagsA = accumarray(D(:), A(:)); %// Compute sums of diagonals (your 'd')
B = B + sumsDiagsA(D); %// Add them to the matrix
```

### Explanation:

First we build a matrix that numbers all diagonals beginning from the rightmost diagonal:

```
>> D = bsxfun(@minus, size(A,2)+(1:size(A,1)).', 1:size(A,2))
D =
     4     3     2     1
     5     4     3     2
     6     5     4     3
     7     6     5     4
```

Then we compute `sumsDiagsA` as the sum of the diagonals via `accumarray`:

```
sumsDiagsA = accumarray(D(:), A(:));
```

The variable `sumsDiagsA` is what you refer to as `d` in your code.

Now we use indexing to the vector containing the sums and add them to the matrix `B`:

```
C = B + sumsDiagsA(D);
```

---

Assuming you have already computed your vector `d`, you don't need the `accumarray`-step and all you need to do is:

```
D = bsxfun(@minus, size(B,2)+(1:size(B,1)).', 1:size(B,2)); %'
C = B + d(D);
```

Comment: I thought there are two inputs - One 2D matrix, say `B` and a 1D array `d`, which would be of length `sum(size(B))-1`?

Comment: @Divakar: Frankly I don't understand the question perfectly. I based my first answer on your answers, but then I just took literally: "*I am writing a script that operates on matrices, and I have run into the problem of needing to add the sum of the diagonals of a previous matrix to the diagonal elements of a new matrix.*"

Comment: @knedlsepp Hmm, well I mostly skipped the text part, and went straight to the diagram part, which made sense to me.